# show/hide Custom component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, repeater, show-hide

i am trying to show user Details on click and upon click of other user Details i want to hide or remove existing user details on the page,  below is my piece of code

**TODO.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {fetchjson} from '../../helpers/helpers';
import Userdetail from "../../components/userdetails/userdetail"; 
export default class Todo extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showComponent: false,
        userData: []
    };
}
handleClick = () => {

    fetchjson('users/' + this.props.tododdate.userid).then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            showComponent: true,
            userData: data
        });

    });

}
render() {
    const thistodo = this.props.tododdate;
    return ( <div className = "row" >
        <div className = "col-md-6" >
        <h3 onClick = {this.handleClick} > USER ID: {thistodo.userid } </h3> 
      <ul className = "list-unstyled" > {
            thistodo.todo.map(todo =>
                <li > < input type = "checkbox"
                checked = {
                    todo.completed
                }
                /> {todo.title}</li >
            )
        } </ul> </div> 
        <div className = "col-md-6" > {
            this.state.showComponent ?
            <Userdetail userprops = {
                this.state.userData
            }/> :
            null
        } </div> </div>
    )
  }
 }
```

**UserDetail.js**

```
import React from "react";
export default class Userdetail extends React.Component{
 render() {
   const thisuserdata=this.props.userprops;
   return (
   <div>
    <label>name : </label>
      {thisuserdata.name}<br/>
      <label>username : </label>
     {thisuserdata.username}<br/>
     <label>name : </label>
   {thisuserdata.name}<br/>
   <label>phone : </label>
    {thisuserdata.phone}<br/> 
   <label>website : </label>
   {thisuserdata.website}<br/>
    </div>
   )}
 }
```

[image]

when i click on user ID:1/user ID:2... i am able to show user details, but what i want to hide user ID:1 details on click on user ID:2 Details.

Comment: one possible solution is: instead of maintaining the `showComponent` bool in each component maintain that in parent of todo component and pass a `function` also from parent to todo and call that `function` from todo to change the `state` in parent, use that bool to show user info, onClick of any user, reset all the values in parent and make true for that particular component, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax

```
{showComponent && <div></div>}
```

based on showComponent value you can show hide div also you can update the value via **setState**